# Save integers as floats

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function prec(numb){
    var numb_string = numb.toString().split('.')

    return numb_string[(numb_string.length - 1)].length
}
function randy(minimum, maximum) {
    var most_accurate = Math.max ( prec(minimum), prec(maximum) );

    return ( ( Math.random() * ( maximum - minimum ) + minimum ).toFixed( most_accurate ) );
}

// returns random numbers between these points. 1 decimal place of precision:
console.log( randy(2.4,4.4) );

// returns random numbers between these points. 3 decimal places of precision:
console.log( randy(2.443,4.445) );

// returns random numbers between these points. Want 3 decimal places of precision. However, get 0:
console.log( randy(2.000,4.000) );

// Why do I get 0 decimal places? Because floats are rounded into integers automatically:

console.log( 4.0 ); // want 4.0 to be logged. Instead I get '4'
```

You don't need to read how the functions work. Just the console logs.

Basically, I need to return a random number between two points to a degree of precision. The precision is automatically derived from the most precise float passed to the `randy` function.

This works fine when the number range is `3.5` `3.7` or `34.4322` `800.3233` but not `2.0`, `3.0` or `4.0000`, `5.0000`

Then the number is appears to be automatically saved as an integer:

`console.log( 2.0 ) //=> 2`

**I want to extend the Number prototype so that `2.0` is saved as `2.0` so that this function can find the precision:**

```
function prec(numb){
    var numb_string = numb.toString().split('.')

    return numb_string[(numb_string.length - 1)].length
}
```

It currently thinks that `3.000000000` has a precision of 0 decimal places because if `3E8` is passed in as the `numb` parameter, it's read as `3`. I want it read as `3.000000000`

While I can do this `randy(2.toFixed(3),3.toFixed(3))` it gets unreadable and it would be undeniably nicer to do this for smaller precisions: `randy(2.000,3.000)`.

Is this possible?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gxCeK/2/)

Comment: You can't change how javascript stores a number internally.  If you want to determine how much precision you have, then you need to just develop your own code to process whatever form of valid number you get.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one number type in JS.
Aside from shortfalls of the type itself (causing headaches in other languages as well), it's a good thing.

If you want to display precision, then use `num.toFixed(n);` to store the number as a string, rounded to the precision you requested.

You can parse the string later in your code, operate on it, and then call `.toFixed(n);` on the result, to perpetuate the precision...

But unless you have specific needs, or are lumping several pieces of code together, are you not going to be concerned with rounding inaccuracies, versus just operating on full-precision values, and then rounding/formatting the end results?

Of course there are plenty of other solutions...

...keep track of the mandated precision with an int, representing the value...  ...or keep an int representing the floating value as an int, based on preferred precision...  `1.235` becomes `[1, 235]`.

...anything is doable.
Subclassing, though, is really not going to be the answer.

Comment: So I have to write this:         `var min = 0, max = 1, opacity = Math.randomNumber( min.toFixed(2), max.toFixed(1) );`? So long winded!

Comment: `function(min, max) { return Math.randomNumber(min.toFixed(2), max.toFixed(1)); }`  :)

Comment: @Starkers in that example, the actual work the browser is doing, mathematically, isn't going to care what degree of precision you're using while you're actually doing the math. All it's going to care about is the precision when it comes out the other end (if you do, indeed, have a system that's expecting a specific precision, and the loss of accuracy that comes with it).  `var x = clampRandom(min, max).toFixed(2)` where `clampRandom` might look exactly like the function @jdphenix wrote above, minus passing arbitrary precisions as params (or deducing them).

Answer (score 0):

you can define a class that helps you solve the problem especially with the toSting function

```
function NewNumber()
{
    this.value = (typeof(arguments[0]) == "number") ? arguments[0] : 0;
    this.decimal = (typeof(arguments[1]) == "number") ? arguments[1] : 0;
    this.Val = function()
    {
        return parseFloat(this.value.toFixed(this.decimal));
    }
    this.toString = function()
    {
        return (this.value.toFixed(this.decimal)).toString();
    }
}
```

Create a number like this

```
var Num = NewNumber(4.123545,3); 
// first argument is the value 
// and second one is decimal
```

To get the value of your variable, you should use the function `Val` like this

```
console.log(Num.Val()); // this one prints 4.123 on your console
```

Then the toString function

```
Num.toString() // it returns "4.123"
(new NewNumber(4,4)).toString(); // it returns "4.0000"
```

in your functions use the toString of the NewNumber class to solve your problem